# How to inherit CSS Menu on each html page linked on Homepage without using any javascript and templates

Tags: html, css

I've task at hand of creating website without using Javascript and templates. I am unable to comprehend after reading many CSS tutorials, that how to inherit same page styles and menus to all linked pages. Do I have to create menu in each pages or is there code to inherit via main.css ? I want same menu fixed on all pages for easy navigation without use of any client side scripting. my main css

```
/* my styles */

html{
    background: white;
}



body {
    font-family:"Verdana";

}


#page {
    width:960px;
    background-image:url("src/school.png");
    margin:20px auto;

}

nav {
    background:#001D2D;
    width:100%;
    height:50px;

}


nav a{
    display:block;
    background-color:#001D2D;
    color:#fff;
    text-decoration:none;
    padding:14.5px;
    float:left;
}

nav a:hover{
    background-color:#15A88C;
}

nav ul li:hover{
    position:relative;
    list-style-type: nones;
}

nav ul li{
    float:left;
}
```

edit*

I understand that I have to link css to all html page, What I want to know is that do I have to copy paste nav tag elements and recreate menu in all linked html pages to inherit css styles?. is that a good practice? any workarounds?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way would be to include the main.css in each page you need it.

So in the html pages between the `<head>` tags place this line:

```
<link type="text/css" href="main.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Edit:

To answer your edit, yes you have copy that portion of HTML you want if you don't want to use templates.

Answer (score 0):

Just make style sheet in in you head tag and `style.css` and mention on every page

```html
<html>
  <head>
 <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css"/>
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <p>this is ur page </p>
    
    
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I understand that I have to link css to all html page, What I want to know is that do I have to copy paste <nav> elements in all linked html pages to inherit css styles?.  is that a good practice? any workarounds?

Comment: Yes it is tag like header, <nav>, section, article, are the best practice to do

Answer (score 0):

Just add this to all of your pages.

```
<link href="MyCss.css" rel="stylesheet" />
```

if you want to added or modify any css coding for any particular page then you can use inline css for that . Highly not recommendable but if its small change you can use inline css.
Eg.

This will replace your default css.

Comment: please look my edited description. do I have to repeat nav element in each html page to inherit my css ?

Comment: Can i see your html pages too?

Comment: it wil use that property automatically if you use nav in your next html page.